# Is there no way to distinguish different generic instantiations runtime in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I come from a C# world and I've just learned about [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java, which put me a bit off. Is there really no way to distinguish `SomeGenericInstance<String>` from `SomeGenericInstance<Integer>` runtime in Java?

I'm asking because I've implemented a super simple pub-sub framework and I wanted to have a generic class `GenericMessage<T>`. It's essential not to send `GenericMessage<String>` to listeners of `GenericMessage<Integer>`. I tried implementing it by having a List of key-value pairs where the key is the `Class` object representing the type of the message. But this code line yields `true` which is a problem...:

`new GenericMessage<Integer>().getClass.equals(new GenericMessage<String>().getClass())`

Comment: You probably need to do something like `publishMessage(genericMessage, Integer.class);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, sorry, it is simply impossible.

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote as this seems to be the only TRUE answer (and you were first to point it out) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using **Java Reflection**. Don't know if it's always a good idea, but it's surely possible. Here's an example:

```
public class Test{

    private List<String> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        Field f = field.getGenericType().getClass().getDeclaredField("actualTypeArguments");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Type[] genericTypes = (Type[]) f.get(field.getGenericType());
        System.out.println(genericTypes[0]);
    }

}
```

Or you can cast directly to ParameterizedType, if it seems any better to you:

```
public class Test{

    private List<String> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
        Type[] actualTypes = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        System.out.println(actualTypes[0]);
    }

}
```

Both examples print: `class java.lang.String`

Now just to leave a more complete answer, the same can be done for a *Map*. As you can see the `getActualTypeArguments()` method returns a `Type[]` and for a *Map*, the key type would be index 0, and the value type would be index 1. Example:

```
public class Test{

    private Map<String, Integer> map;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Field mapField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("map");
        ParameterizedType mapParameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) mapField.getGenericType();
        Type[] actualMapTypes = mapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        System.out.println(actualMapTypes[0]);
        System.out.println(actualMapTypes[1]);
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: You can actually cast the class to a `ParameterizedType` to get the actualTypeArguments. `((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType().getClass()).getActualTypeArguments()`

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I'll edit the answer to show an alternative using this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I guess I can use the Type class or string representation of it as key in my HashMap then.

Comment: What if it's not declared as a field but as an input parameter to a method of type Object? I.e. the method parameter type is Object, but it's instantiated as a List<String> for instance.

Comment: -1 This doesn't really answer the question, which is to distinguish between `new GenericMessage<Integer>()` and `new GenericMessage<String>()` - that is impossible without changing the class/constructor to hold a `Class` token to check against at runtime.

Comment: @Nilzor, I don't think anything can be done in that case, in my attempts all I could see is that it was a `List` of type `E`

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. I guess the final answer is "sometimes" then - unless someone comes up with additional suggestions :)

Comment: @Nilzor Note that it would be possible using this trick if you used `GenericMessage<Integer>() { }` instead - but I would recommend `GenericMessage<>(Integer.class)` like zvzdhk suggested.

Comment: Of course *class declarations* e.g. declarations of fields, methods, superclasses, etc. can be fully inspected. (Which even then does not always give you a concrete class for your case -- the type argument could be a type parameter.) But that doesn't answer the question, which deals with the class of objects (i.e. how they were created), not declared types of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it using next trick:

```
public class Example<T> {

    Class<T> genericType;

    public Example(Class<T> genericType) {
        this.genericType= genericType;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example<Integer> ex1 = new Example<>(Integer.class);
        Example<String> ex2 = new Example<>(String.class);
        System.out.println(ex1.genericType);
        System.out.println(ex2.genericType);
    }
}
```

Output:

> class java.lang.Integer
>
> class java.lang.String

Comment: Although this is true, helpful and may solve my PubSub-framwork problem, I believe it does not answer my question as it adds a precondition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of getting what you're looking for without using reflection (assuming that you are able to make modifications to your pub-sub framework to pass a `Class` token). A big hat-tip to assylias and zvzdhk for pointing me in the direction of class literals.

```
interface GenericMessage<T> {

}

interface StringMessage<T extends String> extends GenericMessage<T> {
    String getString();
}

interface IntMessage<T extends Integer> extends GenericMessage<T> {
    int getInt();
}

interface MessageListener<T> {
    <T> void handleMessage(Class<T> type, GenericMessage<T> instance);
}

// "marker interfaces"
interface StringMessageListener<T extends String> extends MessageListener<T> {

}

interface IntMessageListener<T extends Integer> extends MessageListener<T> {

}

class IntMessageImpl<T extends Integer> implements IntMessage<T> {
    public int getInt() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class StringListenerImpl<T extends String> implements StringMessageListener<T> {

    public <T> void handleMessage(Class<T> type, GenericMessage<T> genericMessage) {
        StringMessage stringMessage = (StringMessage) genericMessage; // Typesafe cast since T extends String on both StringMessage and StringMessageListener
        String message = stringMessage.getString();
        // Do something with message
    }
}

class IntListenerImpl<T extends Integer> implements IntMessageListener<T> {
         // an implementation for the Integer case ...
}

void showTypeChecking() {

    GenericMessage<String> badStringMessage = new IntMessageImpl<>(); // Compile-time check fails due to bad type of new message implementation

    MessageListener<Integer> badIntListener = new StringListenerImpl<>(); // Compile-time check fails due to bad type on new listener implementation

    MessageListener<String> stringListener1 = new StringListenerImpl<>();
    MessageListener<String> stringListener2 = new StringListenerImpl<>();
    MessageListener<Integer> intListener = new IntListenerImpl<>();

    GenericMessage<String> stringMessage = new GenericMessage<String>() {};
    stringListener1.handleMessage(String.class, stringMessage);
    stringListener1.handleMessage(Integer.class, stringMessage); // Compile-time check fails due to bad type on class literal

    GenericMessage<Integer> intMessage = new GenericMessage<Integer>() {};
    intListener.handleMessage(Integer.class, intMessage);

    GenericMessage<String> badIntMessage = new GenericMessage<String>() {};
    intListener.handleMessage(Integer.class, badIntMessage); // Compile-time check fails due to bad type on intMessage

    GenericMessage uncheckedMessage = new IntMessageImpl();
    intListener.handleMessage(Integer.class, uncheckedMessage); // Compiler issues warning about unchecked assignment of uncheckedMessage argument

    MessageListener uncheckedListener = new StringListenerImpl();
    uncheckedListener.handleMessage(String.class, stringMessage); // Compiler issues warning about an unchecked call to handleMessage() method
}
```

It's not directly applicable in this case, but you may find this discussion of the [typesafe heterogeneous container](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA142&ots=yYIjMjrZV4&dq=typesafe%20heterogeneous%20container&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=typesafe%20heterogeneous%20container&f=false) pattern helpful in learning a bit more about Java generics. It's definitely one of the harder parts of the language to master.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to distinguish "a `SomeGenericInstance<String>` object" and "a `SomeGenericInstance<String>` object", because there is no difference. There is just "a `SomeGenericInstance` object".